# C & Lua prevent bad access or double free

Tags: c++, c, lua

I successfully integrated Lua into my C my application, giving scripting access to users.  Now my problem: how can I prevent double free or bad access violations?

I already implement Init and Free functions for each struct, for example:

- `structaInit`
- `structaFree`

I also track every time a struct pointer is linked to another, incrementing the reference count which is present in all of my structs.

However the users could always do something like this in Lua:

```
a = structaInit();

b = structbInit();

structbSetA( b, a ); -- This add ++a.reference

a.reference = 0; 

a = structaFree( a ); -- If a->reference == 0 then I free

-- Then struct b->a is still a valid pointer but that have been free.
```

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can't, you're at the mercy of whoever writes the bad code but that's not your problem.

Comment: You could but the overhead would be ridiculous :\ same way that memcheck and kmemcheck function. They can keep track of this but at a giant performance hit.

Comment: @Jeff: What is bad about that code? If an object exposed to Lua has the ability to store another object exposed to Lua, then the Lua programmer should reasonably expect that the reference to this object will not disappear. The problem is the API. No API should _ever_ directly expose a reference count to Lua. Nor should an API explicitly require Lua code to free something (unless it's something like a file, which has to be closed to free up OS resources).

Answer (score 10):

The problem has to do with ownership. Let's take your Lua scripts:

```
a = structaInit();
b = structbInit();
```

This creates C objects that Lua now *owns*. Lua will decide when to free the memory for these objects.

So what about this?

```
structbSetA( b, a ); -- This add ++a.reference
```

First of all, `structbSetA` should be a member of `b`, via a metatable (so it becomes `b:setA(a)`). But more importantly, who owns `a`?

Lua does. Because it *must* own A; Lua cannot fully relinquish ownership of an object that is still in Lua memory. This means that your internal reference count is ultimately meaningless; the only one that matters is Lua's.

If you intend to store the value of `a` within `b`, such that `b` can reference `a` so long as `b` is still alive, then you need to create this relationship through *Lua* methods. You can't just stick the C pointer to `a` in `b` and expect everything to go well.

The easiest way to do that is to, for each object you create, make a table in the Lua registry that stores the Lua object for any references it has. When an object is destroyed, you go into the Lua registry and remove this table from it, thus leading to the destruction of any referenced Lua objects. Obviously, you will need to change this value when it is modified by later calls to `structbSetA`.

---

Also, why are you exposing this to Lua:

```
a.reference = 0;
```

That's a terrible API. Lua code should *never* have to deal with a reference count. You should also never expose an explicit "free" method to Lua, unless you need Lua to release some resource immediately after it is finished using it. And that should *only* be necessary for OS-type resources like FILE handles and such. For a regular object, let the garbage collector do its job.

Do not expose C-isms to Lua code. Let Lua code look like Lua code.

Comment: Why can't I triple-upvote this answer? :) Especially the last two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it comes down to programming practice you do not really want to prevent it, you actually want to let it error out because that way the person using your scripts knows that they are doing something wrong (same way in obj-c it crashes when you over-release). If you don't want this to happen you might have to keep track of all active pointers on the heap to your structs in a linked list or some structure but I don't think it's worth it.